# Visualforce Re-Usable Text Blocks

Tags: visualforce

I am creating a VF page that is going to have multiple blocks of text that may be used in other VF pages as well.  These blocks will have some CSS formatting.  Does anyone know of a way that I can save these text blocks somewhere and then reference them in the VF pages, similar to what can be done with Static Resources?  I want to have the ability to update the blocks of text easily in 1 area, but also the flexibility to style them on a page by page basis.  Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [CustomLabels](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm&language=en), and putting the CSS into separate stylesheets instead of inline.  Moving the text to labels and the CSS elsewhere gives non-technical admins control over the content while you can concentrate on technical details.

Comment: Thanks Charles!  I ended up creating custom VF Components as that fit my needs.  Thanks for your help!